# Renamed Home Folder, now Dropbox Mac App won't launch

Tags: dropbox, mac

I renamed my home folder using these directions from Apple - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201548

Worked great. However, now when I try to launch the Dropbox app it asks for permission to modify a folder, which no longer exists.

[image: permission problem]

`joshua1` no longer exists, it is now just `joshua`.

I give permission anyway, and then get this error.

`Couldn't start Dropbox
This is usually because of a permissions error. Storing your home folder on a network share can also cause an error. For more information, click the help button below. Please contact Dropbox support with the following info for help:` - long text part copied below.

I obviously need to move my Dropbox folder. But according to this Dropbox support article, I need to launch the app and set that in the preferences - https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/89.

Here is what Dropbox gave me to give to their support. 
`H
bn.BUILD_KEY: Dropbox
bn.VERSION: 3.6.4
bn.DROPBOXEXT_VERSION: failed
bn.is_frozen: True
pid: 1556
ppid: 1
uid: 502
user_info: pwd.struct_passwd(pw_name='joshua', pw_passwd='********', pw_uid=502, pw_gid=20, pw_gecos='Joshua Dance', pw_dir='/Users/joshua', pw_shell='/bin/bash')
effective_user_info: pwd.struct_passwd(pw_name='joshua', pw_passwd='********', pw_uid=502, pw_gid=20, pw_gecos='Joshua Dance', pw_dir='/Users/joshua', pw_shell='/bin/bash')
euid: 502
gid: 20
egid: 20
group_info: grp.struct_group(gr_name='staff', gr_passwd='*', gr_gid=20, gr_mem=['root'])
effective_group_info: grp.struct_group(gr_name='staff', gr_passwd='*', gr_gid=20, gr_mem=['root'])
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH: None
cwd: u'/Applications/Dropbox.app/Contents/Resources'
     real_path=u'/Applications/Dropbox.app/Contents/Resources'
            mode=040755 uid=502 gid=20
     parent mode=040755 uid=502 gid=20
HOME: u'/Users/joshua'
appdata: u'/Users/joshua1/.dropbox/instance1'
         real_path=u'/Users/joshua1/.dropbox/instance1'
                not found
         parent not found
dropbox_path: u'/Users/joshua1/Dropbox'
              real_path=u'/Users/joshua1/Dropbox'
                        not found
              parent    not found
sys_executable: '/Applications/Dropbox.app/Contents/MacOS/python'
                real_path='/Applications/Dropbox.app/Contents/MacOS/python'
                        mode=0100755    uid=502 gid=20
                parent  mode=040755 uid=502 gid=20
trace.__file__: '/Applications/Dropbox.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/site-packages.zip/dropbox/client/ui/common/boot_error.pyo'
                real_path='/Applications/Dropbox.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/site-packages.zip/dropbox/client/ui/common/boot_error.pyo'
                        not found
                parent  not found
tempdir: u'/var/folders/r9/dql9_58x0qq8x54hqtl1sw3m0000gp/T'
         real_path=u'/private/var/folders/r9/dql9_58x0qq8x54hqtl1sw3m0000gp/T'
                mode=040700 uid=502 gid=20
         parent mode=040755 uid=502 gid=20
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dropbox/client/main.pyo", line 3332, in main_startup
  File "dropbox/client/main.pyo", line 1594, in run
  File "dropbox/client/main.pyo", line 796, in startup_low
  File "dropbox/client/main.pyo", line 567, in safe_makedirs
  File "os.pyo", line 150, in makedirs
  File "os.pyo", line 150, in makedirs
  File "os.pyo", line 157, in makedirs
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/joshua1'`

Answer (score 2):

Dropbox support got back to me, and had a fix. Not simple so open up your terminal.

Please save and quit all programs accessing files in the Dropbox folder, and then follow these instructions:

Note: Please be sure to take note or take a screenshot of any Selective Sync settings you may have applied prior to re-installing in case you need to re-apply these settings upon re-install.

1. Stop Dropbox (If needed):

   - Click the Dropbox icon in the menu bar at the top of your screen
   - Click on the gear icon in the Notifications panel and select 'Quit Dropbox'
2. Download the newest version:

www.dropbox.com/install

3. Open your Terminal app (Located at /Applications/Utilities/Terminal)
4. Copy and paste the following lines into the Terminal, ONE AT A TIME, and press ENTER after each one. PLEASE make sure you copy and paste these commands (don't type them by hand), as getting them wrong could cause some harm. You'll be prompted for your computer's admin password (not your Dropbox password) after entering the first command. Keep in mind that the password field in the terminal will remain blank as you type your password. After you type it, just press ENTER.

`sudo chown "$USER" "$HOME"`

`sudo chown -R "$USER" ~/Dropbox`

`sudo chmod -R u+rw ~/Dropbox`

`sudo mv ~/.dropbox ~/.Trash/dropbox.old`

`sudo chmod -N ~`

`sudo mv /Library/DropboxHelperTools ~/DropboxHelperTools.old`

(Note some of these commands didn't actually do anything. I think they were just trying to be super thorough.)

5. Open the .dmg file from step # 2 and double click the Dropbox icon to install Dropbox.
6. Restart Dropbox from the Applications folder, then please sign in and apply any Selective Sync settings you may have had prior to the reinstall during the sign in process. Your account will take a few moments to reindex the files and sync any pending changes.

Comment: Thanks for the question and the reply.

It seems to me that the key thing to do is the `mv/.dropbox ~/.Trash` step